# compare dataGridView cell with picture inside

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I populate DataGridView with data and depending on the data I put an image in the 12th column either succes or fail. My goal is to be able to double-click on the 12th cell and show MsgBox with the status inside. I can pretty much do all whats was asked in the homework. However I can't tell in IF CONDITION; if the image in the 12th row = to succes;

here's the error;System.InvalidCastException : 'L'oerator '=' not defined for type 'Bitmap' and type 'Bitmap'.'

thank you for all the help

```
Private Sub DgvTest_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvTest.CellMouseDoubleClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 12 And dgvTest.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("status").Value = imgList.Images.Item("fail") Then
        Dim numTest As String = dgvTest.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells.Item(0).Value
        For Each i As Test_Auto In lst_Test_Auto
            If i.No_Test = numTest Then
                If i.status = False Then
                    MsgBox("status of test #" & numTest & " ; " & "a generated and error: " & i.message)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could simply store a boolean/string in the [Tag Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tag?view=netframework-4.8) of your cell, and use that to compare instead.  You'd set it when you assign the image...

Comment: I really have no clue how to add to Tag Property, the column 12 is actually the 13th if I count from 1 to 13, sorry if I wasn't clear